# Any way to make XCode Run shortcut global?

Tags: xcode, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any proper or hacky way to make make the XCode Cmd-R shortcut trigger globally?

I.e, while the app is running but not in focus?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a hacky way - Keyboard maestro.

Also pretty sure its possible to do the same just with Apple Script - first call `activate` command on Xcode window and then trigger the shortcut.

If anyone finds a way to send one without activating the window though, will approve their answer.

Answer (score 0):

No man, sorry, not possible and Automator doesn't provide such workflow either.